# Passing parameter via Binding to UserConrol DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have custom user control with the only property - SubHeader.

```
<UserControl x:Class="ExpensesManager.TopSection"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
  mc:Ignorable="d">
<StackPanel>
    <Label Name="Header" Content="Constant header text" Style="{StaticResource Header}"/>
    <Label Name="SubHeader" Content="{Binding SubHeaderText}" Style="{StaticResource SubHeader}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

```
public partial class TopSection : UserControl
{
    public TopSection()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SubHeaderTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SubHeaderText", typeof(string), typeof(TopSection));

    public string SubHeaderText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(SubHeaderTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SubHeaderTextProperty, value); }
    } 
}
```

There are two usages in xaml. First with the constant text:

```
...
<my:TopSection SubHeaderText="Constant text"/>
...
```

Another one using binding:

```
<Page x:Class="MyNamespace.MyPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:my="clr-namespace:My"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
      ...
        <my:TopSection SubHeaderText="{Binding MyModel.SubHeaderText}"/>
      ...
</Page>
```

My page code behind:

```
public partial class MyPage : Page
{
    private MyModel myModel;

    public MyModel MyModel
    {
        get
        {
            return this.myModel?? (this.myModel = new MyModel());
        }
    }

    public MyPage(MyEntity entity)
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.MyModel.MyEntity = entity;
    }
}
```

MyModel code:

```
public class MyModel : NotificationObject
{
    private MyEntity myEntity;

    private string subHeaderText;

    public MyEntity MyEntity
    {
        get
        {
            return this.myEntity;
        }

        set
        {
            if (this.myEntity!= value)
            {
                this.myEntity= value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.MyEntity);
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.SubHeaderText);
            }
        }
    }

    public string SubHeaderText
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("Name is {0}.", this.myEntity.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that second one doesn't work. If I pass the constant text - it is displayed, if I use binding to the other property - nothing is displayed.
Does anybody knows what's wrong with the code? Thanks.

Comment: How did you set the `DataContext` of `TopSection` ?

Comment: I've added the full xaml for TopSection. Datacontext is set this way:
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"

Comment: How is MyHeader created?

Comment: Do you mean MyModel.SubHeaderText? If so - it's a get property. See the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you set `DataContext` on the `UserControl` element. It will cause the following binding

```
<my:TopSection SubHeaderText="{Binding MyModel.SubHeaderText}"/>
```

to be relative to that `DataContext`, which is `UserControl` itself - so it cannot find the value.

To fix this, I suggest you not set `DataContext` on the `UserControl`, but the `StackPanel` inside:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ExpensesManager.TopSection"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  mc:Ignorable="d">
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncesterType=UserControl}}">
    <Label Name="Header" Content="Constant header text" Style="{StaticResource Header}"/>
    <Label Name="SubHeader" Content="{Binding SubHeaderText}" Style="{StaticResource SubHeader}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Many people set `DataContext` on `UserControl` but that's really **BAD**. When you use the UserControl later, you have no idea the `DataContext` is actually set internally and will not respect the outside `DataContext` - really confusing. This rule also applies to other properties.

Comment: This change raises the error in error list: Object reference not set to an object.
Though I was able to run it - it still shows the constant text and fails to show for binding.

Comment: UPDATE: Sorry. I guess that was VS bug. It works correctly now. Great thank you!

Comment: @Julia Check the Output window at runtime, there should be a line telling which binding failed.

Comment: @Julia Great! Many people set `DataContext` on `UserControl` but that's really bad thing since when you use the `UserControl` later, you have no idea the `DataContext` is actually set internally and does not respect the outside `DataContext`. That's really confusing.

Comment: Ding!  We've been caught by this very problem at our company several times.  Be wary of setting the DataContext directly on a UserControl/Window/Page.

Answer (score 0):

`MyModel` is a property in your `DataContext`? Try to check what object is your `DataContext`. If your data context is an object of your class `MyModel` you doesn't need the `MyModel.` part in your binding. 
This kind of bindings always are to objects in your data context.

Hope this tips helps.

Comment: Thank you for your ideas. The MyModel usage was correct. It's a property on my page. And DataContext was set to self.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your UserControl like this:

```
<my:TopSection
x:Name="myControl">
```

Then change your binding to this:

```
<my:TopSection SubHeaderText="{Binding MyModel.SubHeaderText, ElementName=myControl}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set the Model in your `UserControl`

```
public partial class TopSection : UserControl
{ 

 public class SampleViewModel { get; set; }

 public TopSection()
 {
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new SampleViewModel();
 }

 public static readonly DependencyProperty SubHeaderTextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SubHeaderText", typeof(string), typeof(TopSection));

 public string SubHeaderText
 {
    get { return (string)GetValue(SubHeaderTextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SubHeaderTextProperty, value); }
 } 
}
```

**Update**

Since you don't want `Model` to known to the `View`. Create a `ViewModel`

```
public class SampleViewModel : NotificationObject
{  

  public class MyModel { get; set; }
  public class SampleViewModel()
  {
   MyModel = new MyModel() { SubHeaderText = "Sample" }; 
   RaisePropertyChange("MyModel");
  }  
}
```

Comment: Please, see the update. TopSection knows nothing about MyModel. It should have only 1 property set in xaml.

Comment: Well if you don't want it to know your Model. Where is your ViewModel?

Comment: My target was to have the user control which will display any text given (so I used 1 property - I don't think I need Model or ViewModel here).

Comment: @Julia Yeah, you don't need it now. Wait until you get to maintain and extend that class. Your coupling them too much.

Comment: You're right. But my problem was the different and fixed now.
Though I really have no idea how to pass the text to display to ViewModel used in UserControl.

Comment: You set the BindingMode to TwoWay so it'll update the ViewModel